# MobileFirst Platform on IBM Containers

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to bluemix part. I followed link https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/ which is great. Got in all steps.

I have copied my project war file in usr/projects directory as per documents and steps in link. But after completing all steps i can not able to open mobilefirst console. But container is created which I can see on bluemix. Also created public IP. still can not able to open.

So I can not deploy external war file or what on trial version of bluemix? Can someone help me in that.
Screenshot -
[image]

Comment: What do you see though? What page do you see? What error do you see?

Comment: i can see container is created on site of bluemix. But when i try to hit public url to open console. Its not available.

Comment: But what *do you see*?

Comment: sir last I run startserver.sh script. in which it is asking for image url, container name, IP address all mandatory fields are filled. Ip address i can put any IP address right?

Comment: i cant see anything link is not opening. browser giving me link not available. But when I create container directly through site at that i can able to access console.

Comment: @IdanAdar is it IP address issue or something I am doing wrong.

Comment: What if your publicly assigned IP address?

Comment: @IdanAdar its 169.44.10.237

Comment: @IdanAdar I have added screenshot in my question please see that.

Answer (score 0):

"I have copied my project war file in usr/projects directory as per documents" - Where does it written that you should copy the .war file? Instead you should set the PROJECT_LOC property to point to the root directory of your MobileFirst project. Also you can't put any IP, you need to assign one. Read the "Step 3: Using the configuration files" section for more details.

Comment: its written in steps also.. if you didnt provide path then it will take files from project folder.